# How to render ajax error from a controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I am submitting a form with ajax.

In my controller I have something like:

```
if @message.valid?
 render json: { msg: @message.content }
else
 render json: { error: 'Reply could not be sent.' }
end
```

In my view I have the form

```
<%= form_for @message, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Then in my view I have the following javascript

```
$('.message').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
 $(this).before('<p>'+data.msg+'</p>');
  });

$('.message').bind('ajax:error', function() {
 alert("Error: Message could not be sent.");
});
```

I can't get the ajax error to initiate. I assume its how I'm passing the json error message in the controller.

Comment: Did you use remote ajax ?

Comment: Yes. I will add to the question

Comment: add (xhr, status, error) inside second function() may help, not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send the response back to ajax without any status, it assume status as 200(success). Unless you either get syntax error or some authorization error, ajax will always goes into success state. Since its your custom error, i advised not http status code.
Instead you can modified the 'ajax:success' callback function.

`

```
$('.message').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
   if(data.error){
     alert(data.error);
   }
   else{
     $(this).before('<p>'+data.msg+'</p>');
   }
})
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your controller this is it be returned as en error. i usually use the response status 422 (Unprocessable Entity), however it might be more appropriate to use another error code in your case.

```
 if @message.valid?
   render json: { msg: @message.content }
 else
   render json: { error: 'Reply could not be sent.' }, status: 422
 end
```

You can read about response statuses [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) (pay a special attention to error 418 :))